# how to create user in PostgreSQL 11 when PostgreSQL 9 is already installed

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I want to create a user with PostgreSQL. I have running PostgreSQL 9.3, 9.4 and 11.

```
$ sudo service postgresql status
9.3/main (port 5432): online
9.4/main (port 5433): online
11/main (port 5434): online
```

I use PostgreSQL to create a user and check the version.

```
$ sudo su - postgres
postgres@XYZ ~ $ psql
postgres@NX00579 ~ $ psql
```

Output is:

```
                                                            version                                                                
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.3.25 .....  ...... ...... ..... ....... ...... ...... ... 
(1 row)
```

When I created the user in PostgreSQL then it was created with 9.3, not with 9.11.

```
postgres@XYZ ~ $ createuser -P
```

How can I use PostgreSQL 11?

Comment: Run the `psql` binary from 11 and use `-p 5434` to connect to the running 11 server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to connect to the correct server by specifying the correct port:

```
psql -p 5434
```

You can use the 9.3 client with the v11 server, but it would be bettet to use `psql` from v11, either by calling it with the absolute path or by adding the directory containing the executable to the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: How can I use v11?

Comment: Just like I told you in my answer.